# How was the Free Czech Army formed in World War 2?

Tags: world-war-two, czechoslovakia

I am researching my family's history in World War 2. I know that my grandfather joined the "Free Czech Army" and was evacuated from Sete France after France fell. I have found several online resources: (e.g. *[geocities](http://www.geocities.ws/czechandslovakthings/WW2_evacuation.htm)*) but they do not give me much information regarding exactly how the "Free Czech Army" was formed. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: does [learningco](https://leamingtonhistory.co.uk/the-free-czech-army/) answer the question?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I'm not sure that link actually addresses the formation of the Free Czech Army, which (from reading that article) I assume happened before it arrived in Leamington Spa.

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, the Free Czech Army was formed with Czech citizens that fled the Nazi annexion of their country, and later the declaration of war.
Some of them fled continuously the German advance, they fled their country to Poland, then to Romania, to France, and ultimately United Kingdom. There they were formed in brigades.

Some of them fought in Italy, some of them in France, guarding the German "Festung" on the Atlantic coast.